# Shifting windows operation on aggregate date field MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation, timedelta

So, I'm using **mongodb 3.6.0 driver**.

I have a result collection after running this command:

```
db.commands.aggregate([{$project: { _id:0 ,user: 1, purchaseDate: 1}},{$sort: {user: 1, purchaseDate: 1}}],{allowDiskUse: true})
```

Which looks like this:

```
{ "user" : "1", "purchaseDate" : ISODate("2015-03-09T00:18:38") }
{ "user" : "1", "purchaseDate" : ISODate("2015-03-09T09:44:09") }
{ "user" : "1", "purchaseDate" : ISODate("2015-03-09T09:44:11") }
{ "user" : "2", "purchaseDate" : ISODate("2015-03-09T09:15:57") }
{ "user" : "2", "purchaseDate" : ISODate("2015-03-09T11:32:22") }
{ "user" : "3", "purchaseDate" : ISODate("2015-03-09T13:40:15") }
{ "user" : "4", "purchaseDate" : ISODate("2015-03-09T04:18:57") }
{ "user" : "5", "purchaseDate" : ISODate("2015-03-09T14:46:52") }
{ "user" : "6", "purchaseDate" : ISODate("2015-03-09T16:51:19") }
{ "user" : "7", "purchaseDate" : ISODate("2015-03-09T09:37:53") }
{ "user" : "8", "purchaseDate" : ISODate("2015-03-09T16:25:25") }
{ "user" : "8", "purchaseDate" : ISODate("2015-03-09T16:26:20") }
{ "user" : "8", "purchaseDate" : ISODate("2015-03-09T17:12:57") }
```

**I would like to calculate the time elapsed in seconds or minutes between two purchases from the same user**. Making the each document look like this:

```
{ "user" : "1", "purchaseDate" : ISODate("2015-03-09T00:18:38"), "delta_seconds": 0 }
{ "user" : "1", "purchaseDate" : ISODate("2015-03-09T09:44:09"), "delta_seconds": 33931 }
{ "user" : "1", "purchaseDate" : ISODate("2015-03-09T09:44:11"), "delta_seconds": 2 }
{ "user" : "2", "purchaseDate" : ISODate("2015-03-09T09:15:57"), "delta_seconds": 0 }
{ "user" : "2", "purchaseDate" : ISODate("2015-03-09T11:32:22"), "delta_seconds":  6491}

...
and so on.
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following aggregation:

```
db.purchases.aggregate([
    { 
        $sort: { purchaseDate: 1 } 
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$user",
            purchaseDate: { $push: "$purchaseDate" },
            propertyToUnwind: { $push: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$propertyToUnwind",
            includeArrayIndex: "index"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            user: "$_id",
            delta_miliseconds: { 
                $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$index", 0 ] }, 
                    then: 0, 
                    else: { 
                        $subtract: [
                            { $arrayElemAt: [ "$purchaseDate", "$index" ] }, 
                            { $arrayElemAt: [ "$purchaseDate", { $subtract: [ "$index", 1 ] } ] }
                        ] 
                    } 
                }
           }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            user: 1,
            delta_seconds: { $divide: [ "$delta_miliseconds", 1000 ] }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            user: 1
        }
    }
])
```

Basically to get the context of other documents in aggregation framework you need to group them into an array. So after second stage we end up having an array of all dates per user. We're also adding artificial array `propertyToUnwind` because I want to utilize the fact that [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) delivers index of array (`includeArrayIndex` option).

Having this index we can easily subtract two dates (from current index and previous one). If currently processed document has index equal to zero we can return zero because there's no previous one (that's why using [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/index.html) here). [$subtract](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) for dates returns number of miliseconds so we need to divide this field by 1000 to get seconds.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly! Now I understand better how it works the different pipeline stages ^^